# Having an image follow your finger?

Tags: android, image, view

Sooo I"m learning `OnTouchListener()` and how to get the X Y coordinates of my finger. How can I set an Image view to the XY coordinates? I have an imageview created, but I don't know what to use. Should I set new `Layoutparams`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try calling `setX()` and `setY()` on your ImageView object to explicitly set its position, or you could call `setTranslationX()` and `setTranslationY()` on your ImageView to change the position relative to where the image was originally positioned.

Comment: Is this okay to do if it's just in a Linear or Relative Layout? I just checked the imageview codes I can use, and none of those are available.

Comment: They **are** available. `ImageView` extends `android.view.View` and those methods are declared in `android.view.View`.

Comment: They are only available in api 11 and up, so you may not see them if developing for a phone.

Comment: There is also something called 'offsetLeftAndRight' and 'offsetTopAndBottom' which are available since API level 1.